# Recursive method in composite pattern

Tags: java, recursion

Hi i have a components class which can contain components and composite and i am writing a method to calculate the sum total of all the tax in its components.This class is part of a composite pattern code.The problem is my method which is recursive is not working properly i am having a stack overflow but for testing my method i only have two objects in my array list.

```
public class Nobles extends RiruritaniaSubjects
{
    ArrayList vassalsanddukes = new ArrayList();

    public void calculateTaxDueByComponents(){
        Iterator iterator = vassalsanddukes.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            RiruritaniaSubjects vassalandduke=(RiruritaniaSubjects) iterator.next();
            totalTaxdue+=vassalandduke.getTaxDue();
            calculateTaxDueByComponents();
        }
    }
}
```

RiruritaniaSubjects is an abstract class and i have my other composite class extend it.I have edited the code and the stack overflow has stopped but my other problem is it seems to not add on the tax due if a component contains a component.

```
public void calculateTaxDueByComponents(){
    Iterator iterator = vassalsanddukes.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        RiruritaniaSubjects vassalandduke=(RiruritaniaSubjects) iterator.next();
        totalTaxdue+=vassalandduke.getTaxDue();
        vassalandduke.calculateTaxDueByComponents();

    }
}
```

I have decided to post snippets of different parts of my code.The problem i am having now is for e.g i have a noble A then a noble b , then a noble c.If i add noble c to noble b b.add(C). and i add b to a,a.add(B), my calculate Totaltaxdue() is not updating my tax due with the inner noble c.

public class Nobles extends RiruritaniaSubjects {
    ArrayList vassalsanddukes = new ArrayList();

```
public void calculateTaxDueByComponents(){
    Iterator iterator = vassalsanddukes.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        RiruritaniaSubjects vassalandduke=(RiruritaniaSubjects) iterator.next();
        totalTaxdue+=vassalandduke.getTaxDue();
        System.out.println(vassalandduke.getTaxDue());
        vassalandduke.calculateTaxDueByComponents();

    }
}


public double getTotalTaxDue(){
    calculateTaxDueByComponents();
    return totalTaxdue;
}



public class Prince   {
Land land;
ArrayList allprinceSubjects = new ArrayList();


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    RiruritaniaSubjects allsubjects = new Nobles();
    RiruritaniaSubjects allsubject3 = new Nobles();
    RiruritaniaSubjects allsubject4 = new Nobles();
    allsubject4.add(allsubject3, 10);
    allsubjects.add(allsubject4, 10);
    System.out.println(allsubjects.getTotalTaxDue());


}
```

}

By my own workings the output should be 7 because it should be 3.5 for each noble but i am getting 3.5 as the output which is wrong.

Comment: If this is homework, please add the Homework tag.

Comment: But you get a new iterator each time; you never iterate. You just get the first one again and again until your machine falls over. What are you trying to do? Either recurse or iterate, don't do both.

Comment: I need to iterate because i have an array list that contains objects so i need to go through each object

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `calculateTaxDueByComponents` method on `this` rather than to call it on your subcomponents.

Moreover, the calculateTaxDueByComponents is a void method. It doesn't return anything. So it's impossible to add its result (since it doesn't have any) to the tax due by the current component. Your method should probably look like this:

```
public int calculateTaxDueByComponents() {
    int taxDueByThisComponent = getTaxDue();
    int taxDueByThisComponentAndAllItsSubComponentsRecursively = taxDueByThisComponent;
    Iterator iterator = vassalsanddukes.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        RiruritaniaSubjects vassalandduke=(RiruritaniaSubjects) iterator.next();
        taxDueByThisComponentAndAllItsSubComponentsRecursively += vassalandduke.calculateTaxDueByComponents();
    }
    return taxDueByThisComponentAndAllItsSubComponentsRecursively;
}
```

Side note: your code would be more readable and more type-safe if you used generic collections: `List<RiruritaniaSubjects>` rather than `List`.

Comment: Thanks i also observed one more thing ,if a component contains an object ,The method does not go deep or does not recognize the object.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "if a component contains an object". The method does what its Java code tells it to do. What kind of object should it "recognize"?

Comment: sorry the object i meant was Nobles. e.g i have a nobles object A.i then create nobles object b and nobles object c. Then i b.add(c). Then a.add(b).The method does not update the total tax due with my tax from c.

Comment: Thanks jb ,I have a method that returns the total TaxDue.I re posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method from with the method, leading to an infinite loop! Just remove that call:

```
public void calculateTaxDueByComponents(){
    Iterator iterator = vassalsanddukes.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        RiruritaniaSubjects vassalandduke=(RiruritaniaSubjects) iterator.next();
        totalTaxdue+=vassalandduke.getTaxDue();
        // calculateTaxDueByComponents(); DON't DO THIS!
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not so much recursion.

Comment: I have changed the method and noted some errors that i am getting

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that calculateTaxDueByComponents belongs to RirutaniaSubjects.
You are certainly going to have a stack overflow because you are calling it on this. Probably you want to do:

```
public void calculateTaxDueByComponents(){
    Iterator iterator = vassalsanddukes.iterator();
    int totalTaxDue = getTaxDue();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        RiruritaniaSubjects vassalandduke=(RiruritaniaSubjects) iterator.next();
        totalTaxdue+=vassalandduke.calculateTaxDueByComponents();

    }
}
```

Comment: The getTaxDUe method has to be performed on every object

Comment: It will be performed on every object; it is called on the object in which you are currently calculating the tax. For subjects (which don't have any elements in the iterator), it is the only method called.